# Combine two queries in coldfusion

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have two queries in my coldfusion file from two different datasources

Query1: connects to server1 and brings data few columns for a user- date in the datetime format and can be null

`<cfquery name="getUserData"`

For example:

```
Date        User    Col1 Col2 Col3
08/2019     Sam     1     2   3
09/2019     Sam     5     7   9
```

Query2: Connects to server 2 and bring few columns for a user - date in date format.
`<cfquery name="getUserMetrics"`
For example:

```
Date    User Col4 Col5
09/2019  Sam  4    5
```

Now I need to achieve this from these two queries in coldfusion and get data like this:

```
Date      User    col1  Col2  Col3  Col4   Col5
08/2019   Sam     1     2      3
09/2019   Sam     5     7      9     4      5
```

How can I achieve combining queries in coldfusion and get my result,

thank you

Comment: Read [About Query of Queries](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/using-query-of-queries/about-query-of-queries.html)

Comment: That didnt help, I need to combine two queries from datasources into one

Comment: Depending on your database engine, you might have better luck using linked servers.  This is a sql server term, but the concept is supported by at least one other product, oracle.

Comment: I would definitely look into linked servers in SQL. This query would be much easier to accomplish in SQL.

Comment: What flavor/version of CF and SQL?

Comment: Are these 2 different Servers or just 2 different databases on the same server?

Comment: Two different servers,

Comment: The cleanest solution would be linked servers as per other suggestions, although that has its performance issues too. If you can't/won't go down that route then there are at least a couple of other alternatives of varying nastiness depending upon the nature and size of your data. 
1) Bulk insert the results of server1 query into a temp table on server2, then you can do the necessary joins against the temp table. 
2) Use queryNew / queryAddRow / querySetCell to create an empty query object with all of the desired columns, then loop over both queries to populate it. https://cfdocs.org/querynew

Comment: This link might be helpful http://www.justskins.com/forums/query-of-queries-combining-83724.html